# Fly: Failed to ping docker registry

Tags: docker, concourse, fly

I am trying to run a simple build by passing input task to the concourse. Here is my fly command,

```
fly -t tutorial e -c inputs_required.yml -i some-important-input=.
```

and my yml file,

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
- name: some-important-input

run:
  path: ls
  args: ['-alR']
```

I am getting the below error message,

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
failed to ping registry: 2 error(s) occurred:

* ping https: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
* ping http: Get http://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

errored
```

Please note that I am not behind a proxy. I am also not able to ping *https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/*.

Comment: Ah, I was about to point possible proxy issues. Can you `curl` the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is your host cannot reach docker registry which is `docker.io` by default.

I am not familiar with `fly`. But I think the image source in your yaml file `{ repository:busybox}` should be a specific image which could be used in command `docker pull`.

For addition, you may try a local image on your host first. Then try a remote image in some remote registry.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I am able to run `docker pull busybox` successfully.